# Symfony console change directory using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have a Laravel project and i want to run a command on a directory.

`"\storage\app\public\my-stores\store 1\themes\theme 1\"`

Let's say I want to get the contents of that folder using the "dir" command. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. 

What I want to do is run a command on a specific directory.
Let's say I want to run:
>`theme configure --password=[your-password] --store=[you-store.myshopify.com] --themeid=[your-theme-id]`

I want that command to be run on "\storage\app\public\my-stores\store 1\themes\theme 1\" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Refer to this documentation.
http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.html#method___construct

```
$process = new Symfony\Component\Process\Process('dir', storage_path() . '\\app\\public\\my-shopifies\\store 1\\themes\\theme 1\\');
$process->run();
$process->getOutput();
```

Comment: That's correct. I don't see it in their documentation anywhere but [it's there](https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/e498803a6e95ede78e9d5646ad32a2255c033a6a/Process.php#L1124).

Answer (score 5):

The current documentation doesn't mention it but there is a `setWorkingDirectory()` method.

```
$process = new Symfony\Component\Process\Process(['dir']);
$process->setWorkingDirectory('\storage\app\public\my-stores\store 1\themes\theme_1');
$process->run();
echo $process->getOutput();
```

Looks like there are lots of other public methods not mentioned in the docs.

https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/509ba166ae24c2227227c8ad54a3916bbd137422/Process.php#L1108

Answer (score 0):

Or the Symfony [Finder Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html). It is up to you.